# Admin LTE content height, bug? how to fix?

Tags: css, adminlte

Why footer is so big?

[image: Before]

When I resize page or zoom page, it's ok, why? How fix that?

[image: After]

Comment: fixed **$.AdminLTE.layout.fix()**

Comment: Can you share the code ? So I can analyse.

Comment: Below every HTML page, include the following Script:

<script>
    $('body').layout('fix');
</script>

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, but it seems that the min-height css property causes this annoying issue.

I have fixed this issue by adding the following inline CSS

```
<style>
        .main-sidebar, .left-side {
            min-height: 0%;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, there is an offical way to fix this, though it has changed.

Here is the V3.2 solution:

```
$('body').Layout('fixLayoutHeight')
```

Documentation:
https://adminlte.io/docs/3.2/javascript/layout.html